# I want to implement this NOT IN query as a series of OUTER JOINs, to try and optimize execution

Tags: sql, join, optimization, outer-join

I've been trying to follow other examples I've seen on SO, but they just don't seem to match my use-case (or, I'm too thick to see how they apply). I have a situation using a toy database, where I want to get some information and I need to go through a pivot table to do so. The task I've set myself is:

> Write a query that lists the full name and email address of all tutors that aren’t teaching any classes in Semester 2, 2018.

The table `tutors` contains the tutor information, `unittutor` is a pivot that has `tutor.staffID` and `unit.unitID` and of course `unit` has all the units in it.

I am able to easily achieve this like so:

```
SELECT
     t.firstName
    ,t.surname
    ,t.email
FROM tutor t
WHERE t.staffID NOT IN (
    SELECT ut.staffID
    FROM unittutor ut
    INNER JOIN unit u ON ut.unitID = u.unitID
    WHERE u.semester = 2 AND u.year = 2018
);
```

I am *convinced* (but could very well be wrong) that I can implement this as two `LEFT JOIN`s... however everything I've tried so far as not worked. Can anyone give some *general* advice as to a process I can follow to achieve this? I feel like I'm tripping up on the filter; when I get the `unittutor`s, obviously the tutor I expect to exclude (by which I mean the tutor I want to end up with) is there, because that tutor does in fact teach a unit, but not in semester 2. When I then join `unit`, how do I filter out the units that match `year = 2018 AND semester = 2`?

I don't get the opportunity to write much SQL at work, but I'm not on a project which might require a fair amount, and I want to be able to produce the most optimal code I can.

Answer (score 0):

Your "convince" is correct.  The two `left join` version looks like:

```
SELECT t.firstName, t.surname, t.email
FROM tutor t LEFT JOIN
     unittutor ut
     ON ut.staffID = t.staffID LEFT JOIN
     unit u
     ON ut.unitID = u.unitID AND u.semester = 2 AND u.year = 2018
WHERE u.unitID IS NULL;
```

It is important that the conditions on `u` go in the `on` clause and not in the `where` clause.  If they go in the `where` clause, the outer join turns into an `inner join` and doesn't do what you want.

This may return duplicates, which can be removed using `SELECT DISTINCT`.  Because of the duplicates, `NOT EXISTS` or `NOT IN` is a better approach.

Comment: Is that a typo in the line `ON ut.staffID = u.staffID LEFT JOIN`? `unit` does not contain a column for `staffID`, did you mean `t.staffID` ?

Comment: Running that query gave me an interesting result. It appears that it doesn't return only the teachers who aren't teaching in semester 2... it gives me a set of all the teachers against the units they are teaching, and merely excludes units that are in semester 2 [link - png 20kb](https://i.imgur.com/kmaaxrx.png) I omitted the `u.unitID` filter for demonstration's sake

Comment: @ThanasiPoulos . . . Yes, I can see how it would do that.  `NOT EXISTS` or `NOT IN` is a better approach.